# How to fix "Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1 while running splitTextToColumns(' ')"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My initial data range is a sheet of seven columns and a variable number of rows.

I am only interested in column 5 (E) which contains text like

```
21 BCN SJP[WR] -COR(WR) PPG ST 06/05 23:45 ( HAPA-95%-P-15/04 )
```

I am trying to split this text into columns using a space delimiter. After splitting, I will rearrange the columns into a preferred order.

My code so far is:

```
function mnEmpties() {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("M/N Empties");
  sheet.deleteRow(2);
  sheet.setFrozenRows(2);  

  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows(); 
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn(); 

  var range1 = sheet.getRange(3,5,lastRow);//first 02 rows are header values, problematic range
  range1.splitTextToColumns(' '); 

var range = sheet.getRange("F:F"); 
 range.setValues(range.getValues().map(function(row1) {
  return [row1[0].replace("BOXNHL", "BOXN")];
 }));

// //USING THE SAME RANGE
  range.setValues(range.getValues().map(function(row2) {
  return [row2[0].replace("BTFLN", "BTPN")];
 }));

  var values1 = sheet.getRange(3,7,lastRow).getValues(); 
  var values2 = sheet.getRange(3,8,lastRow).getValues();   
  var results1 = []; 
  for(var i=0; i<lastRow; i++){
    results1[i] = [values1[i][0]+""+values2[i][0]];
  }
  sheet.getRange(3,7,lastRow).setValues(results1); 

  var values3 = sheet.getRange(3,11,lastRow).getValues(); 
  var values4 = sheet.getRange(3,12,lastRow).getValues();   
  var results2 = []; 
  for(var i=0; i<lastRow; i++){
    results2[i] = [values3[i][0]+""+values4[i][0]];
  }
  sheet.getRange(3,11,lastRow).setValues(results2); 

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
  var insert1 = sheet.getRange(3,6,lastRow).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(3,1,lastRow).setValues(insert1);

  var insert2 = sheet.getRange(3,5,lastRow).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(3,2,lastRow).setValues(insert2);
```

Every time I run this code there is an error message:

```
Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1 (for code line var range1 = sheet.getRange(3,5,lastRow);)
```

and the script doesn't continue. I tried changing the range values many times, but to no avail.

Comment: One of your problems is that the number of rows in for example range1 is not lastrow but lastrow-2 or lastrow-startrow+1.  The third parameter is number of rows,

Comment: If you have been running this code repeatedly, are you sure that `sheet.deleteRow(2);` hasn't accidentally deleted the rows of the sheet? It's deleting it every time

Comment: Firstly, thanks to the the Tin Man for editing my post and making it more relevant. Madhavi - sheet.deleteRow(2) is working fine. @Cooper - lastrow-2 is not working, but lastrow-startrow+1 is working with some hiccups, i am still testing it and will get back to you with the feedback. Thanks!!

Comment: @Cooper lastrow-startrow+1 is working, but randomly. Sometimes the function runs smoothly, but sometimes it gets stuck at var range1 = sheet.getRange(3,5,lastRow-startRow+1). I do not change anything in the meantime. Strange!!

Comment: Helllo there @AbhaySinghChauhan, can you confirm you have data in your sheet? Also, what do you mean by "sometimes it gets stuck"? Can you do a `console.log(lastRow)` right before the mentioned line? What are you getting?

Comment: @ale13 thanks for the interest. Stuck = script was not running beyond range1 code line. But, now function is running smoothly without any error. Thanks to all especially Cooper :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can be solved by checking the appropriate parameters for the `getRange` methods you have used.

Therefore, you should do the following change:

```
var range1 = sheet.getRange(3,5,lastRow-startrow+1)
```

**Reference**

- [Sheet Class Apps Script - getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows)